# Good reliability analysis with reverse coded items: further checks needed?

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability

After conducting an **exploratory factor analysis** on a set of data, I have obtained 3 factors, whose items (can) make sense from a theoretical perspective — even though some **negatively worded items** grouped in an unexpected way.
As a second step, after reversing the negatively worded items, I ran a **reliability analysis** for each factor. The Cronbach's alpha ranged from .8 to .9. Given these results, is it *generally* ok to just continue with other analyses (*I am using EFA scores directly for a cluster analysis*) or I *must* check further for a bias in the responses for those negatively worded items? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "grouped in an unexpected way"? And I think it would be helpful if you posted your EFA output, if possible.

Comment: It means that we expected some items to be grouped under different factors (from what we learned from the literature). Sorry, I cannot post the EFA output. Yet, I can tell you that there are very few cross-loadings (and they do not refer to the items mentioned above). I hope this helps.

Comment: And you conducted the reliability analyses as EFA suggested, not according to the original theory? In that case I see no problem in what you're doing. Of course you need to take into account that original theory -suggested structure was not fully supported by data when interpreting the results, but if you are fine with the EFA solution, I see no reason why you couldn't use it.

Comment: First, why not cluster on the original data? Do you have a huge number of questions?  Second, there is some literature to suggest that negatively worded items can group together.  Third I am not sure that reliability analysis on the factors will be helpful, it would be very surprising if the factors weren't highly reliable.

Comment: @Sointu: Yes, I have conducted the reliability analyses on the factors suggested by EFA. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @PeterFlom: by “clustering on the original data”, do you mean that I run cluster analysis without EFA? Wouldn't that be unusual? I think it would not be accepted (no?), as I have put together factors (with items) from two separate studies. By the way, I have 32 items / questions (for 500 participants) whose loadings go from .419 to .875. Thanks for the other comments!

Comment: What makes you think it would be unusual or not accepted? This link https://www.researchgate.net/post/Should-a-factor-analysis-always-precede-a-consensus-cluster-analysis-technique seems to argue against EFA before clustering.

Comment: @PeterFlom: thanks for the link! It is an interesting discussion. Yet, the person asking the question also states that she has had a confirmation that those factors are indeed present (and she is asking whether to use factor scores or not in the cluster analysis). In my case, I am pretty confident that I need a confirmation of the existence of those factors. Indeed, my findings show that multiple factors exist, but they do not really reflect those from the literature (which can occur, I guess, since I am using a different sample and I have modified some items).